# Loop over every line in an Excel file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I have an Excel file with many columns, but I need only columns `NAME`, `Cost` and `Time`. I need to loop in my Excel line by line but for columns Name/Cost/Time, to save values in a variable.

```
 If FileUpload1.HasFile = False Then

        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        'Dim FolderPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Upload")

 Protected Sub ButtonVerify_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonVerify.Click


    If FileUpload1.HasFile = False Then

        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        'Dim FolderPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Upload")

        Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\Upload\" & FileName
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath)

        Dim existingFile = New FileInfo(FilePath)
        Dim pack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(existingFile)
        Dim workBook As ExcelWorkbook = pack.Workbook


        If workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then
            Dim currentWorksheet As ExcelWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First()


            Dim Requester As String = currentWorksheet.Cells(30, 2).Value

        End If

    End If

    LBL_Error.Text = Nothing

    LBL_Status.Text = "Your file have been upload in your form. Please complete your Sample Order!"
End Sub
```

Where `If workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0` then I need to loop every value from cell and finally calculate the average of all times in a box.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through lines only for certain columns you can do like this:

```
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim DateRng As Excel.Range
Dim AccountsRng As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long

WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

DateRng = WS.Columns(2)     ' Change the '2' as necessary.

With DateRng
    For i = 1 To .Count
      'Do your stuff
    Next i
End With
```

In this way you choose the column you wanna use, following this explanation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197266.aspx

Excel.Worksheet.Columns(1) will be your column A

Comment: What is XlApp i have trouble with dat?

Comment: Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application